# How is the zero-lift drag coefficient calculated?

Tags: aerodynamics, drag, performance-calculation

The drag coefficient is usually given as a funtion of the lift coefficient and the zero-lift drag coefficient ($c_{D0}$):

$c_D=c_{D0}+k\cdot c_L^2$

How can I calculate/estimate $c_{D0}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look it up in reference books. For wings, the [NASA report server](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?N=0&Ntk=All&Ntt=wing%20drag%20coefficient&Ntx=mode%20matchallpartial) is your friend. For complete aircraft, there is some data available in books about pre-design of aircraft. The one I have is [Synthesis of Subsonic Airplane Design](https://repository.tudelft.nl/islandora/object/uuid%3A229f2817-9be9-49b6-959a-d653b5bac054) by E. Torenbeek, and gives the following numbers for $C_{D_0}$

- 0.014 - 0.020 for high subsonic jet aircraft
- 0.018 - 0.024 for large turboprops
- 0.022 - 0.028 for twin engine piston aircraft
- 0.020 - 0.030 for small single engine aircraft, retractable gear
- 0.025 - 0.040 for small single engine aircraft, fixed gear
- 0.06 for agricultural aircraft without spray system
- 0.070 - 0.080 for agricultural aircraft with spray system

Appendix F of the same book gives a method for more detailed estimation in the pre-design phase, when no wind tunnel data is available, based on data of the components that make up an aeroplane.